# How to Fix PhpArtisan failed "Class 'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm clone project from github and got this error

When i run php artisan serve i got this :(

In Application.php line 612:
Class 'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not found

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. The class that is being required from a file is not there. Either missing completely or it's a path issue

Comment: The solution is not to delete the class but fix the path then.

Comment: Then another question arises. Is that your project? Cause you seem not aware of what's inside your project

Comment: In your project root run `composer install`

Comment: Did you run `composer install` AFTER cloning the project from git?

Comment: yes after clone i run composer install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just you need run `composer install`

Comment: run `composer dumpautoload` and `php  artisan cache:clear`

Comment: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct
   key lengths.

Comment: run `php artisan key:generate` for generate new key